# lapply with a large list over a large data.table

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata

I'm working with a pretty large data set "mutualhold" (~170 mio rows) that contains monthly information for 16881 unique investment funds with many different holdings each.

```
dput(head(mutualhold,5))
structure(list(crsp_portno = c(1003678L, 1003678L, 1003678L, 
1003678L, 1003678L), report_dt = c("31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", 
"31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001"), eff_dt = c("31/12/2001", 
"31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001"), percent_tna = c(3.88, 
3.47, 2.64, 2.5, 2.48), cusip = c("36960410", "59491810", "30231G10", 
"93114210", "17296710"), permno = c(12060L, 10107L, 11850L, 55976L, 
70519L)), .Names = c("crsp_portno", "report_dt", "eff_dt", "percent_tna", 
"cusip", "permno"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000047d0788>)

dput(tail(mutualhold,5))
structure(list(crsp_portno = c(1050207L, 1050207L, 1050207L, 
1050207L, 1050207L), report_dt = c("30/11/2017", "30/11/2017", 
"30/11/2017", "30/11/2017", "30/11/2017"), eff_dt = c("21/12/2017", 
"21/12/2017", "21/12/2017", "21/12/2017", "21/12/2017"), percent_tna = c(0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02), cusip = c("92553P20", "65122910", "90187B40", 
"05722G100", "G5785G10"), permno = c(91063L, 60986L, 93070L, 
NA, 14011L)), .Names = c("crsp_portno", "report_dt", "eff_dt", 
"percent_tna", "cusip", "permno"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000047d0788>)
```

My goal is to extract the columns "report_dt", "cusip" and "percent_tna" "crsp_portno" and store them in a list. The final list should be of length 16881  and contain data.tables with the extracted values for each of the "crsp_portno"s. My first hunch was to do this with lapply, and it certainly is possible:

```
require(data.table)
sample <- list(1003678L, 1050207L)
tnas <- lapply(sample, function(x) mutualhold[crsp_portno %in% x, .(report_dt, percent_tna, cusip)])
```

This is working, but it is pretty slow, and I don't know if I'll be able to perform further operations efficiently with the resulting list. I would really appreciate suggestions for a more efficient way to perform such operations, if necessary I can provide a larger sample, but this data is not publicly available so I can not share it here unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Per @Frank's suggestion, you can use `by` instead of `f` as argument name while splitting data table.

split data by `crsp_portno`

```
split(x = setDT(mutualhold)[, .(report_dt, cusip, percent_tna, crsp_portno)], by = 'crsp_portno' )
```

**Data:**

```
mutualhold <- structure(list(crsp_portno = c(1003678L, 1003678L, 1003678L, 1003678L, 1003678L), report_dt = c("31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001"), eff_dt = c("31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001", "31/12/2001"), percent_tna = c(3.88, 3.47, 2.64, 2.5, 2.48), cusip = c("36960410", "59491810", "30231G10", "93114210", "17296710"), permno = c(12060L, 10107L, 11850L, 55976L, 70519L)), .Names = c("crsp_portno", "report_dt", "eff_dt", "percent_tna", "cusip", "permno"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
mutualhold <- rbind(mutualhold, structure(list(crsp_portno = c(1050207L, 1050207L, 1050207L, 1050207L, 1050207L), report_dt = c("30/11/2017", "30/11/2017", "30/11/2017", "30/11/2017", "30/11/2017"), eff_dt = c("21/12/2017", "21/12/2017", "21/12/2017", "21/12/2017", "21/12/2017"), percent_tna = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02), cusip = c("92553P20", "65122910", "90187B40", "05722G100", "G5785G10"), permno = c(91063L, 60986L, 93070L, NA, 14011L)), .Names = c("crsp_portno", "report_dt", "eff_dt", "percent_tna", "cusip", "permno"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L)))
```

Comment: This is brilliant! As a comparison: With lapply, the exact same thing took longer to process with only 50-100 IDs. This was a matter of only a few seconds when using split. I'm amazed by the data.table package's efficiency, thank you for the quick solution :)